# How to add on website facebook like box with comment box together?

Tags: facebook

Here is code for like box we need to add comment box and like box in each post...

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/OneLife4Live" data-width="600" data-height="400" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="false" data-header="flase" data-stream="true" data-show-border="true">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you keep logged in facebook on another tab.

you will get Likebox and commentbox directly when you facebook logged in browser.